# Function recursion in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, recursion

I am trying to plot the following function in Latex with Tikz:

[image]

My current code looks like this below, which does not include the summation.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \datavisualization [visualize as smooth line=length,
                      clean ticks,
                      scientific axes=clean,
                      x axis={label=$x$, length=10cm},
                      y axis={label=$f(x)$, length=10cm},
                      all axes={grid}]
data [format=function] {
    var x : interval [1:9];
    func y = 4^(\value x - 1) * 1.7320508075688772935 / 4 / 3^(\value x) / 3^(\value x);
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Is is possible to use a recursive way in order to display the grow of the sum?

Thanks for suggestions and alternatives.

Comment: Yes, with the math library. See the example on the Fibonacci series.

Comment: You should really first convert your code to an example that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` and can be compiled.